# Is it possible for an Azure c# function to silently failing?

Tags: c#, azure, http, appinsights

I have an azure function that is hooked up for application insights.

There is an intermittent bug in the function.  In the function a http post is made, and 90% of the time this call is fine, but sometimes its like it just doesn't return at all. No exception is thrown, and all logging to splunk stops at that point.

In Application insights there is no evidence of the function crashing or timingout.  There is no evidence of an error in in any form.

if I put 1000 requests on and 900 succeed, App insights reports that there were 900 
requests and I cant find anything referencing the remain 100?

Where are they? What could have happened to them?

I know that the function was triggered 1000 times as the splunk logs prior to the http post total 1000.

The exception handling, which is simply catching "Exception" so should catch anything, is not triggered, even if there was an exception inside my exception handling, I would expect that to appear in app insights under failures.

I really dont understand how this can be happening.

Help me stack overflow, your my only hope.

Laura

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks,  I will put an mre together tomorrow

Comment: If you don't have request timeout and requests never finish then you'll see the picture you described.

Comment: I dont understand how the request could never finish though, as the default timeout for an azure function is 5mins. In my tiny mind, I seem to stuck focusing on, it must either "Timeout, finish, or error".  Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks for looking at this guys, I haven't put on a MRE as it very intermittent it would be very reproducable. I have discovered a few things though which I will put on as answer in case it help anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

It can look like the function is failing silently and it kind of is as I am unable to find any evidence on app insights that it has actually run.

This function is a triggered from an azure queue. 
The maxDequeueCount had been set = 1. So when it had failed to complete the process for that queue item, its not a failure in the sense of an exception, and when we increased the maxDequeueCount the queue message was rerun and succeeded.